# Cоздать экземпляры всех классов, которые наследуются от интерфейса. Java

Tags: java, наследование, интерфейс

Например, есть интерфейс "Квартира".
Нужно пройтись по всем типам квартир, которые наследуют интерфейс "Квартира", (одно-, двух-, трех- и т.д.) и, скажем, добавить их в `ArrayList`.

Можно ли такое сделать? Если да, то как?

Comment: Такое можно только сторонними [либами вместе с аццкой рефлексией](http://stackoverflow.com/a/520339/3212712) сделать. Скорее всего, вашу задачу можно решить изящнее, если вы раскроете ещё подробностей.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, но либы-то написаны людьми, значит можно и без либ. Просто двумя строками это не обойдется.

Comment: @Nofate, ну я это примерно и имел в виду - без либ долго, а всё, что связано с рефлексией у меня, по моей практике, всегда вызвано незнанием как решить задачу без оной)

Comment: Очень сильно похоже на то, что вы переизобретаете dependency injection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это реализуемо. Это даже может быть полезно, когда вы пишите какой-нибудь расширяемый фреймворк и заранее не знаете, с какими объектами придется работать, а заставлять пользователя регистрировать классы вручную (как это происходит, например, в JDBC) почему-то неприемлимо.

В общем случае вам нужно:

1. Выполнить сканирование CLASSPATH
2. Проверить все найденные классы через рефлексию на наследование интерфейса/класса.
3. Вызвать через рефлексию конструктор.

> Сразу стоит понять: либо вы точно знаете (требуете), какой конструктор
>   будет реализован во всех классах, либо используете дефолтный
>   конструктор без параметров (а он создается автоматически, только если
>   нет других явных конструкторов).

Пункты 1 и 2 несколько утомительны для реализации вручную. К счастью есть отличная библиотека [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), которая позволит сделать это двумя строками кода. Допустим, нас интересуют все реализации интерфейса `HttpHandler`:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections();
Set<Class<? extends HttpHandler>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(HttpHandler.class);
```

И все! Теперь осталось перебрать все экземпляры `Class` и вызвать, допустим конструктор без параметров:

```
List<HttpHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
for (Class<? extends HttpHandler> clazz : classes) {
    try {
        handlers.add(clazz.newInstance());
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("Не удалось создать экземпляр: " + clazz.getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

---

> ## Но!
>
> *Если вы еще не пишете свои фреймворки, то есть вероятность, что вы как-то неправильно, ломая ООП, пытаетесь решить совсем иную задачу*.

---

Альтернативные реализации сканера CLASSPATH:

- https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner

Answer (score 3):

Следующий метод находит все классы находящийся в указанном `jar` архиве реализующие определенный интерфейс:

```
Collection<Class<?>> getAllInterfaceImplementations(String pathToJar,
                                                    Class<?> interfaceType) throws Exception {
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
    Enumeration<JarEntry> e = jarFile.entries();

    URL[] urls = {new URL("jar:file:" + pathToJar + "!/")};
    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

    Collection<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
        if (je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")) 
            continue;

        String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - ".class".length());
        className = className.replace('/', '.');
        Class type = cl.loadClass(className);
        if (interfaceType.isAssignableFrom(type))
            classes.add(type);
    }

    return classes;
}
```

Использовать вот так:

```
String pathToJar = "<путь до JAVA_HOME>/rt.jar";

for (Class<?> type : getAllInterfaceImplementations(pathToJar, Collection.class))
    System.out.println(type.getName());
```